how to place squares correctly (libgdx)
I have a problem with placing three squares in the right place, this is probably the fourth attempt to do it, I tried to watch guides but they are all hopeless and do not explain anything, and there is nothing written about it on libgdx.com
this is what it's supposed to look like
what does it look like
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private Stage stage;

    public Main(){

    }

    public Texture createTexture(Color color, int x , int y){
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(x,y, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setColor(color);
        pixmap.fill();

        Texture texture = new Texture(pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();

        return texture;
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);


        Table root = new Table();
        root.setFillParent(true);
        stage.addActor(root);

        Image button = new Image(createTexture(Color.ROYAL, 300,300));
        Image button2 = new Image(createTexture(Color.ROYAL, 200,100));
        Image button3 = new Image(createTexture(Color.ROYAL, 200,100));

        root.add(button);
        root.row();
        root.add(button2).width(200);
        root.add(button3).width(200);

        root.setDebug(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        ScreenUtils.clear(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }


    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }
}



You could try adding an inner Table into the second column of the first row, and then add the two smaller Images as rows to that.

In the example above I've added some paddings to the rows to make it clearer, but it works just as well without them.
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    Table root = new Table();
    root.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(root);

    Image button = new Image(createTexture(Color.ROYAL, 300,300));
    Image button2 = new Image(createTexture(Color.ROYAL, 200,100));
    Image button3 = new Image(createTexture(Color.ROYAL, 200,100));

    root.row().pad(10);
    root.add(button);

    // This table is only there to hold the two Images on the right,
    // they get one row each.
    Table inner = new Table();
    inner.row().pad(10);
    inner.add(button2).width(200);
    inner.row().pad(10);
    inner.add(button3).width(200);

    root.add(inner);

    root.setDebug(true);

